# How can I create a form which updates website content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a simple CMS and I need website content to be editable via a simple form.

Is there a tutorial I can follow for this? Thought I had it covered after all the social networks I've built in video guides but apparently not.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little please?

Comment: Does this help? www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPor5ErX_90

Comment: @OllyTenerife I'm just looking to have a form that can be edited and submitted which will then update a text element on the html website.

Answer (score 1):

It's only a file editing form or database row updating.

Any tutorial about file edition or database update will help you.